# Nesting mpi calls with mpi4py

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, python-3.4, mpi4py

I am trying to use mpi4py to call a second instance of an mpi executable.

I am getting the error:

```
Open MPI does not support recursive calls of mpirun
```

But I was under the impression that is exactly what Spawn is supposed to be able to handle - i.e. setting up a new communicator within which another mpi command could be launched.

The test code:

parent.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
import sys


rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
new_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Split(color=rank, key=rank)
print(new_comm.Get_rank())
new_comm.Spawn(sys.executable,
                           args=['test.py'],
                           maxprocs=4)
```

which calls test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
import os
import sys

comm = MPI.Comm.Get_parent()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

cwd=os.getcwd()
directory=os.path.join(cwd,str(rank))
os.chdir(directory)


os.system('{}'.format('mpirun -np 4 SOME_MPI_EXECUTABLE_HERE'))



print("Finished in "+directory)
os.chdir(cwd)

comm.Disconnect()
```

I'm running with:

```
mpirun --oversubscribe -np 1 parent.py
```

Using openmpi 2.0.0 with gcc, and python/3.4.2

Anyone have any bright ideas as to why this is happening.....

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `test.py` wrapper? I believe you are supposed to `spawn(SOME_MPI_EXECUTABLE_HERE), ...`.

Comment: The wrapper is needed as the MPI_EXECUTABLE_HERE that I call is not written in python, and so will not run with the sys.executable interpreter. The piece of mpi code that i am calling within the python script s written in fortran.

Comment: I agree with @Zulan, you should start the executable directly via the MPI_Spawn call.

Comment: Yep - you were both right. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code that resolved your issue as answer to your own question and feel free to accept it so that it is immediately clear that you have found a solution.

Comment: Just a hint: instead of splitting the world communicator into as many single-process communicators as processes are out there, simply use `MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn()`.

Comment: Thanks Hristo - what I was aiming for there was, for example to call the script on 4 processes, which then splits and spanws a 4 process call to the MPI_EXECUTABLE. Thereby filling up, say, a 16 core machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code seems to perform the way I wanted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
import sys
import os

rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
new_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Split(color=rank, key=rank)
print(new_comm.Get_rank())

cwd=os.getcwd()
os.mkdir(str(rank))
directory=os.path.join(cwd,str(rank))
print(rank,directory)
os.chdir(directory)


new_comm.Spawn("SOME_MPI_EXECUTABLE_HERE",
                  args=[""],
                           maxprocs=4)
```

run with:

mpirun --oversubscribe -np 4 parent.py

Seems to start 4 instances of SOME_MPI_EXECUTABLE each running on 4 cores.

(Thanks to Zulan)

Comment: The comment of @Hristo under the original question still applies. Instead of creating `new_comm` you can simply use `MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn`. This will give the same results as the code you posted here and would make this answer even more helpful (I myself started off from this answer, thanks btw., and it took me a while to understand the meaning of `Split`, `color`, `key` before I understood that this isn't even necessary)